# How should household chores be split for non-parent, different work-hour couples?

Tags: work-environment, relationships

My significant other and I have been together for years, but this is still an evolving discussion. We work different lengths of hours. One of us works a full time job, the other a part time job.

What are fair methods to determine how the chores should be divided? An even split? A disproportional amount to the person who works less hours? If yes to the latter, how should it be calculated?

The simple math solution would be Full time hours worked minus part time hours worked is the amount of additional hours the part time person should work. But considering the emotions of the two involved the simple math solution does not work. The end goal is to come to agreement that does not leave one feeling like an indentured servant, nor the other like they work non-stop.

Comment: This is something you and your significant other need to figure out for yourself. You want a method that both of you are ok with, not what strangers on the internet suggest.

Comment: Only the two of you can decide what's a fair distribution and what is not.  A better IPS question would be "we've decided to do this; now how do we best implement it?"

Comment: I'll also comment that keeping track of how hours doesn't sound like a great idea. I'd be more inclined to discuss chores I would do/can do vs would never do/not experiences (washing dishes vs car maintenance).

Comment: Could this question be migrated to PersonalProductivity.SE, maybe? In a certain  way it *is* a matter of productivity...